# Awk script to get time averages

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with timestamps in the format:

`HH:MM:SS.MS`

e.g.

> 00:04:02.08
>
> 00:04:01.08

Each timestamp is on a different line, usually just two lines in a file

I need to write an awk script to calculate average of these times. I am quite naive in *awk* scripting, so if someone can please give me a code-snippet, it will a lot of help.

Even a shell script (bash) solution will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

```
/..:..:..\./ {
  ++count
  split($0,a,":");
  seconds = (a[1] * 60.0 + a[2]) * 60.0 + a[3]
  print $0, seconds
  alltime += seconds
}
END {
  if (count > 0) {
    avgtime = alltime / count
    print count, alltime, avgtime
    mins = int(avgtime / 60.0) % 60
    hours = int(avgtime / 60.0 / 60.0)
    secs = avgtime % 60.0
    printf("%02d:%02d:%05.2f\n", hours, mins, secs)
  }
}
```

---

And running it...

---

```
$ cat test.data
other stuff

    00:04:02.08
more stuff

    00:04:01.08

more stuff
$ awk -f q.awk < test.data
    00:04:02.08 242.08
    00:04:01.08 241.08
2 483.16 241.58
00:04:01.58
$
```

---

Comment: If you are selling this on rent-a-coder please don't tell me about it. :-)

Comment: +1 But the regex could be improved maybe something like /[0-9]{1,}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.{1}[0-9]{0,3}/ as an entry like "#Time should be specified as HH:MM:SS.UUU" would through the average off

Comment: Thanks a lot, be assured I ain't selling this at RentACoder. :) Need it as a part of a batch script i need to write at my work.